# Right way to combine group of collections

Tags: java, multithreading, list, collections, java-stream

I have done some code to combine in parallel group of collections which contains pairs[String,Integer], Example

Thread 1
[Car,1][Bear,1][Car,1]

Thread 2
[River,1][Car,1][River,1]

Result should be collections of each unique pair key (sorted alphabetically)

[Bear,1]

[Car,1][Car,1][Car,1]

[River,1][River,1][River,1]

My solution to do this like what shown below but sometime i don't get expected result or ConcurrentModificationException gets thrown from the list that contains result collections

```
List<Collection<Pair<String, Integer>>> combiningResult = new ArrayList<>();

private void startMappingPhase() throws Exception {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    Invoker invoker = new Invoker(mappingClsPath, "Mapping", "mapper");
    List<Callable<Integer>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String line : fileLines) {
        tasks.add(() -> {
            try {
                combine((Collection<Pair<String, Integer>>) invoker.invoke(line));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                executor.shutdownNow();
                errorOccurred = true;
                return 0;
            }
            return 1;
        });

        if (errorOccurred)
            Utils.showFatalError("Some error occurred, See log for more detalis");
    }
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(tasks.size() + " Tasks");
    System.out.println("Started at " + formatter.format(new Date()) + "\n");


    executor.invokeAll(tasks);

    long elapsedTime = System.nanoTime() - start;

    partitioningResult.forEach(c -> {
        System.out.println(c.size() + "\n" + c);
    });


    System.out.print("\nFinished in " + (elapsedTime / 1_000_000_000.0) + " milliseconds\n");
}

private void partition(Collection<Pair<String, Integer>> pairs) {

    Set<Pair<String, Integer>> uniquePairs = new LinkedHashSet<>(pairs);

    for (Pair<String, Integer> uniquePair : uniquePairs) {

        int pFrequencyCount = Collections.frequency(pairs, uniquePair);

        Optional<Collection<Pair<String, Integer>>> collResult = combiningResult.stream().filter(c -> c.contains(uniquePair)).findAny();
        if (collResult.isPresent()) {
            collResult.ifPresent(c -> {
                for (int i = 0; i < pFrequencyCount; i++)
                    c.add(uniquePair);
            });
        } else {
            Collection<Pair<String, Integer>> newColl = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < pFrequencyCount; i++)
                newColl.add(uniquePair);
            combiningResult.add(newColl);
        }

    }
}
```

I tried CopyOnWriteList insisted of ArrayList but sometimes it gets incomplete result like

[Car,1][Car,1] insisted of three entries, My question

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do without getting ConcurrentModificationException and incomplete result?

[An example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fopi.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to modify a single collections from multiple threads you will need to add a synchronized block or use one of the JDK classes supporting concurrency. These will typically perform better than a synchronized block.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/collections.html